# SQL date and time select query incorrect time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query where the view table in postgres is getting "record" from another table with jsonb records where the output is like this >["Created": "2022-06-27T18:32:36Z","Modified": "2022-06-27T18:32:36Z"]

But the view is giving back inaccurate time, so I would like to know a solution to time format please.

```
  to_timestamp(checklist.record ->> 'Time'::text, 'HH24:MI:SS'::text)::time without time zone AS "time",
    timezone('utc'::text, timezone('Europe'::text, to_timestamp(checklist.record ->> 'Modified'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))::date + to_timestamp(checklist.record ->> 'Modified'::text, 'HH24:MI:SS'::text)::time without time zone AS modified,
    timezone('utc'::text, timezone('Europe'::text, to_timestamp(checklist.record ->> 'Created'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))::date + to_timestamp(checklist.record ->> 'Created'::text, 'HH24:MI:SS'::text)::time without time zone AS created,
```

I tried changing and using different time format like HH:MI:SS

Comment: Why not use `(record ->> 'Created')::timestamp at time zone 'Europe/Berlin'`

Comment: you mean like  ``timezone('utc'::text, timezone('Europe/berlin'::text, to_timestamp(checklist.record ->> 'Created'::text, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'::text)))::date + to_timestamp(checklist.record ->> 'Created'::text, 'HH24:MI:SS'::text)::timestamp at time zone 'Europe/Berlin AS created, `` sorry because I am kinda new to SQL so If possible I need more clear answer :c

Comment: No you don't need all those nested conversion to `time` and `date` which you then put together to a `timestamp` A **single** expression `(record ->> 'Created')::timestamp at time zone 'Europe/Berlin'` should be enough.

Comment: I am getting errors without nested conversions is there another way to do this ?

Comment: Then your real data doesn't match the example in your question. https://dbfiddle.uk/v8yhsNY0

Comment: Now it is working ! there was small change needed to record from jsonb. Thank you !